# SQLitePCL.SQLiteResult returning "BUSY" on Step() even after Disposing the Database Connection

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, uwp, database-connection

I am developing an UWP app and trying to insert rows in a database table on a button click event. Here is the query for the same:

```
SQLiteConnection dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection
      (Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\" + fileName + "\\" + fileName + ".db"));

var selectDB = @"*sample insert statement*";

ISQLiteStatement selectCall = dbConnection.Prepare(selectDB);

var t = selectCall.Step();

dbConnection.Dispose();
dbConnection = null;

selectCall.Dispose();
selectCall = null;
```

The insert query is executed successfully for the first time (var t="DONE"). The problem I am facing is that after the first execution, the database is getting locked (var t="BUSY") for some reason. The same problem persists even after calling the Dispose() function. Am I missing something here ? Is there any better way to do it? This is my first time working with SQLite. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that these `Dispose` calls actually happen (exceptions or other flow control statements could interfere).

To ensure that objects are disposed, you should use `using`:

```
using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(...))
using (var selectCall = conn.Prepare("..."))
{
    var t = selectCall.Step();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I established a database connection as soon as my database was downloaded and that fixed my issue. The problem arose as I was creating a new connection for every database operation, which resulted in a locked database. Disposing that connection would still not solve this issue, not even setting the connection object to null would help. So using a single database connection object solved the issue, which should be the general practice. Hope this answer helped.